# How can I migrate AWS RDS database through eb cli (django postgres)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a django project deployed with elastic beanstalk CLI.
I added a postgres database (AWS RDS), the connection is runnning.

My database is still empty. How can I run migration commands or "python manage.py createsuperuser" inside of eb shell?

When I open `eb ssh <env>` and try `ls`, nothing is shown. Stepping one directory back with `cd ..` and again `ls` shows me *ec2-user*, *healthd* and *webapp*. I have not the permissions to enter these folders. Isnt it possible, to run python commands inside of eb ssh?

I did also try container commands, .ebextensions/db-migrate.config:

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "python manage.py makemigrations"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate --first main initial && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: <app>.settings
```

After commiting and deploying again with `eb deploy`, I get this error:

> eb deploy
> Creating application version archive "app-xxxx".
> Uploading: [##################################################] 100%
> Done...
>
> 2021-02-22 12:57:12    INFO    Environment update is starting.
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:05    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:21    INFO    Instance deployment successfully
> generated a 'Procfile'.
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:23    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For
> details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:24    ERROR   [Instance: i-xxxx] Command failed on
> instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an
> error..
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:24    INFO    Command execution completed on all
> instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:24    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on
> instance id(s) 'i-xxxx'. Aborting the operation.
>
> 2021-02-22 12:58:24    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
>
> ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.

Why are the commands failing? Any advice is appreciated. Btw, I have no problems with deploying with the local sql db.

### UPDATE:

eb-engine.log refers me to cfn-init.log. This is the output:

> 2021-02-22 16:49:43,624 [ERROR] Command 01_makemigrations (python
> manage.py makemigrations) failed
>
> 2021-02-22 16:49:43,624 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of
> postbuild_0_django_test: Command 01_makemigrations failed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 542, in run_config
> CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
>
> File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 260, in build
> changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
>
> File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line
> 117, in apply
> raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name) ToolError: Command 01_makemigrations failed

In the Path I see python 2.7 (?) but actually Python 3.7 is running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2. I also tried executing the command with "python3".

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) answer your question?

Comment: I used exactly this tutorial to setting everything up. But the configuration mentioned in "Add a database migration configuration file" is not working either.

Comment: Did you check out the `eb-engine.log` that's mentioned in the output? It should tell you more details.

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: eb-engine.log reffers me to cfn-init.log. Added the output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that django is not loaded at that point.

Solution:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: |
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate
```

Logs referring you to `eb-engine.log` and to `cfn-init.log`, but I found the final hint in `cfn-init-cmd.log`:

> 2021-02-23 11:08:34,019 P5022 [INFO]  ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

I did also try it for "createsuperuser". No errors at all, but also no new user created. There is no active command line to enter username/password. I try to update my answer if I found a solution for createsuperuser.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose an alternate approach:

Rather than running Django management commands from within the eb shell, you could adjust the `DATABASE` [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases) of your local Django project to the remote database, and execute management commands from your local terminal.

This would be useful for running commands ad-hoc, such as `createsuperuser`, but for routine maintenance commands, like `migrate`, you'd want to stick with the  `container_commands` approach as part of your deployment process.

Finally, if you're determined to run `createsuperuser`, specifically, within the eb shell, then you can use `container_commands` to do so non-interactively, with some additional settings configured. From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser):

> When run interactively, this command will prompt for a password for the new superuser account. When run non-interactively, you can provide a password by setting the DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD environment variable. Otherwise, no password will be set, and the superuser account will not be able to log in until a password has been manually set for it.
>
> In non-interactive mode, the USERNAME_FIELD and required fields (listed in REQUIRED_FIELDS) fall back to DJANGO_SUPERUSER_<uppercase_field_name> environment variables, unless they are overridden by a command line argument. For example, to provide an email field, you can use DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL environment variable.